# Why is Shiva called as Brahman by Tulasidasji?

Tags: shiva, ramayana, rama, brahman

Tulasidas ji writes "jeev anek, ek srikanta" Or there are many jivas but only one god, the husband of Shri.

So that would imply that one and only God is Lord Rama ie husband of Sri, then why does he call Lord Shiva as Brahman in his Rudrashtaka and Vinay Patrika etc.?

Comment: Your answer from DB 1.8: *“Vedas, Purānas and other Sāstras that Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Maheśvar, these three Devas are eternal. None is superior to them in this Brahmāṇḍa. Brahmā creates all the beings, Viṣṇu preserves and Maheśvar destroys all in due time. These are the causes of creation, preservation and destruction. The Trinity Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Maheśa are **really one form**, indeed, Trinity in Unity and Unity in Trinity.”* DB 3.6: *“The stupid man who will find any difference between you three, will go to hell; there is no doubt in this. He who is Hari, is Śiva; He who Śiva is Hari”*

Comment: However when you have a specific Upasya Deva, you must stick to him. That’s the way of Sadhana and to get the mind to concentrate on only one. You can refer to Mr. Ross: [Is it helpful to worship multiple deities](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44736/20129). This means you mustn’t accept anything connected with any other god, despite the knowledge that they aren’t different. That’s why Shaivites like Gnanasambadhar etc in their Pasurams say they won’t worship any other god, similarly the Vaishnavas don’t worship other gods.

Comment: Tulsidasji too acknowledges this fact and calls Shiva thus. But, Tulsidasji praises Lord Shiva (other god) so much because besides Shri Rama (Vishnu), Tulsidasji had also experienced Lord Shiva’s vishesh kripa and he played an instrumental role in helping Tulsidasji realise the ultimate. You can have a further look at : [Is the Vedic supreme god different from the Puranic supreme God](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43910/is-the-vedic-supreme-god-different-from-the-puranic-supreme-god/43915#43915) for further information.

Comment: @Archit what's DB? and u ca move these comments into answer.. :)

Comment: @YDS okay will try slowly slowly as time permits to write an answer :). DB is Devi Bhagavata Purana.