# Worshipping other Gods other than IsthaDeva

Tags: vishnu, gods, worship, prayer

Is it okay to pray other Gods other than Istha Deva? My Grandmother used to say that we should pray only one God. What does that purans and scriptures say? Wouldn't the IsthaDeva get angry on worshipping other Gods?

Comment: I’ve read many people say you should only pray to one. I’ve never been able to choose between Durga and Kali, personally. They are both forms of Devi so I justify it that way. But yeah you’re apparently supposed to pick only one form for bhakti marg. Though I did read of some bhakts who don’t obey that rule. I don’t know if they are considered as doing bhakti incorrectly or whatnot. Since I def can’t choose between Kali and Durga, I pray to both of them equally as I couldn’t force myself to select only one of them.

Comment: Worshipping (being devoted to) one God is the ideal .. but we do have to worship various deities for various purposes ... for example, before the start of any Puja we need to worship Lord Ganesha whether he is the Ishta or not. Similarly many other deities (like Dasha Dikpalas) are worshipped on a daily basis as part of various rituals. But devotion usually remains towards the Ishta Devata only for a particular person.

Comment: When a Vedic aspirant performs Yajna he will worship various deities none of which may be his Ishta but still he does it as part of a process ... Related Q --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44735/4732